# K-means keeps generates words before and after as clusters as if they are not clustered at all

Tags: python-2.7, k-means

[image: Input data]

[Extracted words before and after features][2]

[image: Clustering results]

I'm currently running K-means algorithm. However, I'm getting inaccurate clusters. The first image is my input data. The last image is the clustering results. As we can see, the clustering results keep returning words nearby the target word as clusters as if they have not been clustered (compare clustering results and the input data). I'm not sure what am I doing wrong with the extracted features. My extracted features are as follows:

- 1st column -> target word
- 2nd column -> index of the target word
- 3rd column -> 1 word before
- 4th column -> 2 words before
- 5th column -> 1 word after
- 6th column -> 2 words after

Could someone please help out? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the images to your posts and provide some sample code to make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: @A.J. I have posted the images. There are 2 hyperlinks above there and you can click on it and view them. Thanks.

Comment: That is what I mean—add the images to your post not links.

Comment: @A.J. I'm so sorry about that. Since I'm not achieving enough reputation yet and therefore I'm not allowed to add images to my post. Only links are allowed.

Comment: I was unaware, I will edit it for you :)

Comment: @A.J. I am so sorry for the inconvenience caused. At least 10 reputations are required and currently I have only 6 even after you have added me another 5.